# How do I download Minecraft forge 1.8.1 on my iPad?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I really want a certain mod super bad but I have to get Minecraft forge but all of the tutorials I find are for computer, what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

The only option here is to buy the Java Edition of minecraft and play it on a computer. The Java edition can run on Windows, MacOS and Linux.

Forge is for the Java edition of Minecraft, not the Pocket, Console or Bedrock editions of minecraft.